# Setting a delegate property of a controller to self is causing a crash in my app

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, delegates

I have 3 controllers:

SearchViewController

CollectionViewController

MainViewController

**In short**

In CollectionViewController I can access SearchViewController by tapping the magnify glass in the nav bar. I can then search for a specific item. Then select a result from the rows returned. Once I tap a row the SearchViewController is dismissed and a query is performed on the CollectionViewController.

However on MainViewController things don't work the same. Because when the SearchViewController is accessed from the MainViewController and dismissed it's the MainViewController that appears because that is where the SearchViewController was initialized from so I have to do some extra work to get me to the CollectionViewController to perform the query. I performed in first paragraph.

There is a protocol/delegate method I set in the MainViewController that notifies the CollectionViewController when the SearchViewController is dismissed that is causing the app to crash. I can't figure out why. Please read on to for a better explanation of what is going on.

**In long**

Customer types what they want to search for in the search box of the SearchViewController and when they tap the row in the associated tableView of results the SearchViewController is dismissed and it's parent CollectionViewController is now on screen. When this controller is dismissed I use a delegate to notify CollectionViewController that the SearchViewController was dismissed.

**Notify CollectionViewController about dismissal of SVC then perform a query:**

```
- (void)searchViewControllerDismissed:(VAGSearchViewController*)searchViewController withTitleForObject:(NSString *)titleString
{
    _searchTitleString = titleString;
    [self setObjects:nil];
    [self performQuery];
}
```

This all works fine. However I have another controller MainViewController. SearchViewController can be accessed from MainViewController but I can't dismiss and perform a query the way I did when I accessed SearchViewController from CollectionViewController because when the SearchViewController is dismissed MainViewController is present on screen because it was the controller I accessed the SearchViewController from.

What I decided to do was detect which controller initialised SearchViewController then use the same delegate method from above to notify that controller when the SearchViewController was dismissed.

**Inside SearchViewController:**

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]; 

    // If count of child view controllers is greater than 1 then we are not on main table view controller  
    if ([[[self presentingViewController] childViewControllers] count] > 1) {
        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:^{
        [[self delegate] searchViewControllerDismissed:self withTitleForObject:[[cell textLabel] text]];
    }];
    } else {
        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:^{
        [[self delegate] searchViewControllerDismissed:self withTitleForObject:[[cell textLabel] text]];
        }];
    }
}
```

This works fine. So now I created a protocol inside MainViewController.

**Inside MainViewController.h:**

```
@class VAGMainTableViewViewController;
@protocol VAGMainTableViewControllerDisappearedDelegate <NSObject>
- (void)mainTableViewControllerDisappearedwithTitleForObject:(NSString *)titleString;
@end

@interface VAGMainTableViewController : UITableViewController
@property (nonatomic, weak) id<VAGMainTableViewControllerDisappearedDelegate> disappearDelegate;
```

What I wanted was this delegate method to then notify CollectionViewController that SearchViewController had been dismissed from MainViewController then perform a query.

Here is the code inside MainViewController.m:

```
- (void)searchViewControllerDismissed:(VAGSearchViewController *)searchViewController withTitleForObject:(NSString *)titleString
{
    self.disappearDelegate = self;
    [[self disappearDelegate] mainTableViewControllerDisappearedwithTitleForObject:titleString];
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"garmentsCollectionSegue" sender:nil];
}
```

**This is crashing with:**

```
[VAGMainTableViewController mainTableViewControllerDisappearedwithTitleForObject:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xf0140f0
```

When I comment out the line where I set the disappearDelegate line the crash goes away and I am pushed to the CollectionViewController (garmentsCollectionSegue). But the data passed in the delegate method is received by CollectionViewController obviously because a delegate is set.

I've done enough messing around and I think the problem I'm having is caused by not properly setting a delegate or not setting it in the correct place.

Would appreciate some help.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are setting the MainViewController as delegate of itself. I don't think that is what you want.

You want to use that delegate protocol to inform the CollectionViewController of what happens in the MainViewController, right?

Then CollectionViewController should be the disappearDelegate.

So try instead:

```
CollectionViewController *collectionVC = //this depends on your app structure, get the controller
self.disappearDelegate = collectionVC;
```